# how to resolve semantic exception[Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found tablename?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, hive

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 10001, cause: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found tablename
```

When i access tables in terminal it works fine but when i try to run jsp with a query on tomcat in eclipse then it gives the above exception.How to resolve these kind of exceptions?thank you..

Comment: *"When i access tables in terminal "* -- do you use the `hive` CLI (fat client) or the `beeline` tool (JDBC thin client)?

Comment: I use hive CLI. I configured hive-site.xml  as local metastore should i configure it as remote metastore..? or something else.Thank you for the response .

Comment: I configured remote metastore even..! which didn't solve my table not found exception..what may be the root for this problem?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter ...I am new to both hive and eclipse. could you please help me..!.

Comment: I do provide additional information if necessary.I desperatly require suggessions  please anyone help me..!!

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter plzz help me..

Comment: *"Help"* - how?? You don't explain what kind of Hadoop architecture you use (bare-metal multi-node cluster? cloud-based cluster? sandbox?), the distribution you use, the version of Hadoop/Hive you use, the Metastore back-end you set up (MySQL? PostgreSQL? Derby by default?), where you run the Metastore and HiveServer2 services, whether or not you have some High Availability set up, whether or not you have Kerberos set up *(advice: don't mess with that )*. Hadoop is not a toy. It's complicated. First become an experienced Linux SysAdmin, then you can play with distributed systems.